# Prove that $W_0^{1,p}$ is a Banach space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

> $\textbf{Problem}$ Prove that $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a Banach space where $\Omega$ be an open and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

$\textbf{Proof}$  $\quad $Let $\{u_n\}$ be the Cauchy Sequence in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Then, $\{u_n\}$ be also the Cacuhy Sequence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Since $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is a Banach space, there exists $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ such that $\Vert u-u_n \Vert _{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. We suffices to show that $u \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Since $u_n \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$, there exists $\phi_{n_j} \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$ such that $\Vert u_n - \phi_{n_j}\Vert _{W^{1,p}(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0 $ as $n_j \rightarrow 0$.

Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\Vert u - \phi_{n_j} \Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}\leq \Vert u-u_k \Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}+\Vert u_k-u_n\Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}+\Vert u_n-\phi_{n_j}\Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}
\end{align*}
(i) There exists $N_1>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\Vert u-u_k\Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}<\epsilon/3
\end{align*}
for $k>N_1$. ($u_n$ converge to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$)

(ii) There exists $N_2>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\Vert u_k-u_n \Vert_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}<\epsilon/3
\end{align*}
for $n,k>N_2$. ($u_n$ Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$)

(iii) There exists $N_3>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
\Vert u_n-\phi_{n_j}\Vert _{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}<\epsilon/3
\end{align*}
for $n_j>N_3$. ($u_n \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$)

Consequently, $\phi_{n_j} \in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ converge to $u$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. i.e, $u\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$.

I'm not sure my proof is right....

I want to know where my proof is wrong..

Any help is appreciated....

Thank you!

Comment: It seems that what you're proving here is the following general fact: if $B$ is a metric space and $A \subseteq B$, then the closure $\bar{A}$ (defined as the set of all possible limits of sequences in $A$) is a closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is right.
But according to the definition of $W^{1,p}_0{\Omega}$, which is $W^{1,p}_0{\Omega}$ is the completion of $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. So I think it's no need to proof $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is a Banach space, because it's natural.

Comment: I also agree with your answer... But, in our homework, we can't use that $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ is the completion of $C^{\infty}_c(\Omega)$ and the closed subspace of Banach space is a Banach space... Anyway, thank you!!

Comment: there is a same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983140/how-can-i-prove-that-w-0k-p-omega-is-complete?rq=1